# How to send the pdf file through C# ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I need to send the PDF file stored on the server side through ASP.NET Web API, and I have to show at client side using Angular. And I also need to show the preview first before giving downloading options for PDF at client side..

I need to get that file from server and show the preview and download option to user at client side using Angular

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a WEB API Project
2. Add a Controller and add the below code in it :

   ```
       [Route("api/pdf")]
       [ApiController]
       public class PdfController : ControllerBase
       {
           [HttpPost("upload")]
           public IActionResult UploadPdf()
           {
            var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];

           // Process the uploaded file as needed (e.g., save to a location)
            // Example: Save the file to the server
            var filePath = "path/to/save/" + file.FileName;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
             file.CopyTo(stream);
             }

            return Ok("File uploaded successfully");
       }

       [HttpGet("download")]
       public IActionResult DownloadPdf()
       {
          // Example: Read the PDF file bytes from a location
          var filePath = "path/to/pdf/filename.pdf";
          var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

          // Return the PDF file to the client
          return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf", "filename.pdf");
       }
    }
   ```
3. In startup.cs file configure the size

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // Other configurations...

       services.Configure<FormOptions>(o => 
       {
           o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
           o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case you are uploading large files
           o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
       });
   }
   ```